# Make a request from NodeJS to REST API

Tags: node.js, postman

I am testing a REST API. It works perfectly fine on Postman. Now I wanted to call it from my Node project page. In order to achieve that I copied its generated code from Postman, I select `NodeJS Request` option, copied code in a function as shown below:

```
function detect(){
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect',
  qs: 
   { returnFaceId: 'true',
     recognitionModel: 'recognition_02',
     returnRecognitionModel: 'false',
     detectionModel: 'detection_01' },
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '4c4871bd-0028-5d5d-48b7-0843ews75a',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     host: 'centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'ocp-apim-subscription-key': 'f890808ddc3440c0b3d51093ce12d558' },
  body: { url: 'https://i.ibb.co/34fvwYNp/sa.png' },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
}
```

When I run this function, I get this error -

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

How do i call this API from my NodeJS page ?

Comment: So, there is no such thing as a "nodejs page" so that makes me think maybe your'e trying to run this in a browser.  That's not how you run nodejs code.  You run it from the command line in the node environment as in "node yourscript.js".  If you run it properly in nodejs and you're not trying to use an ESM module file, but rather the older style CommonJS module, then `require()` will be defined for you.

Comment: Not the source of this problem, but the `request()` library has been deprecated and should probably not be used in new code.  You can look at the list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  I'm personally using the `got()` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which is natively built for promises (something the `request()` library never did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running this in a browser you can select the "JavaScript Fetch" code option in postman instead of the "nodejs request" one. You can't use nodejs in the browser directly.
Postman will give you code that looks more like this but with more details and no 'require':

```
fetch('https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect', {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```